# XSLT : Adding new tags and values for it

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to add new fields with values in XSLT. I found the below link useful, but I could add only one field and value. I want to add multiple fields and values for it.

For reference :[XSLT: If tag exists, apply template; if not, choose static value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791053/xslt-if-tag-exists-apply-template-if-not-choose-static-value)

input:

```
 <root>
     <item>
        <country>Brobdingnag</country>
      </item>
    <item>
        <test/>
     </item>
 </root>
```

XSLT:

```
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org 1999/XSL/Transform">
         <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
           <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
           </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="item[not(country)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <country>Lilliput</country>
        </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
  <root>
     <item>
         <country>Brobdingnag</country>
     </item>
     <item>
        <test></test>
        <country>Lilliput</country>
    </item>
 </root>
```

Same way i need to add multiple fields.. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more details with regards to your particular xml / xsl & output / expected output.

Comment: Have edited and gave the link again for the reference. Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output though based on that input?  I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do based on the description.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. In the above example, a new field is added. "country". If i try to add one more field, say "State".. 

<country>Lilliput</country> is replaced with
<State>xxx</State>
I want both fields to be added..

Comment: Sorry, at this point I'm still not confident attempting an answer. Perhaps you mean you want something like "<xsl:template match="item[not(country) and not(state)]">" to avoid the new node?

Comment: I didn't try if that works. But i am trying like this "<xsl:template match="item[not(country)</xsl:template>" "<xsl:template match="itemnot(state)]></xsl:template>" as seperate templates.. But only the last template is able to create the field in output xml

Comment: Hey thank you so much.. I am able to get multiple fields in output xml if i do it your way.. Like this "<xsl:template match="item[not(country) and not(state)]">" .. Thanks again.. Sorry for all confusion

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the questin correctly, you just want an additional conditional.

for input

```
<root>
  <item>
    <country>Brobdingnag</country>
    <state>State of Fiction</state>
  </item>
  <item>
    <test/>
  </item>
</root>
```

xslt

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[not(country) and not(state)]">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <country>Lilliput</country>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

output

```
 <root>
   <item>
     <country>Brobdingnag</country>
     <state>State of Fiction</state>
   </item>
   <item>
     <test></test>
     <country>Lilliput</country>
   </item>
 </root>
```

Comment: I have mentioned clearly in another answer. Thanks for your help. Really Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It works this way..

for input :

```
<root>
    <item>
        <country>Brobdingnag</country>
    </item>
    <item>
        <test/>
    </item>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org 1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="item[not(country) and not(State)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        <country>Lilliput</country>
        <state>State of Fiction</state>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output :

```
 <root>
    <item>
        <country>Brobdingnag</country>
    </item>
    <item>
       <test></test>
       <country>Lilliput</country>
       <state>State of Fiction</state>
   </item>
 </root>
```